# looping over regression models in an function

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a function called `R2_null` it compares 2 fitted model and gives an output. The first model `m0` is a constant. But is there a way I can loop over other models after `m0` at onece?

For example, is it possible to do: `R2_null(m0, m1.nc, m1.gmc, m1.cwc, m1.cmc)` but get the exact same result as shown in the example of use by `cbind` multiple calls to `R2_null`?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

d <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/cmc.csv')

m0 <- lmer(dv ~ 1 + (1|id), d)

d <- d %>% 
  mutate(iv.gmc = iv-mean(iv)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(iv.cm = mean(iv),
         iv.cwc = iv-iv.cm) %>% ungroup 


m1.nc <- lmer(dv ~ 1 + iv + (1|id), d) # no centering
m1.gmc <- lmer(dv ~ 1 + iv.gmc + (1|id), d) # grand mean centering
m1.cwc <- lmer(dv ~ 1 + iv.cwc + (1|id), d) # centering within cluster
m1.b_w <- lmer(dv ~ 1 + iv.cm + iv.cwc + (1|id), d) #Between & within


R2_null <- function(m0, m1){
  
  VarCorr(m0) %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    select(grp, var_m0 = vcov) %>% 
    left_join(VarCorr(m1) %>% 
                as.data.frame %>% 
                select(grp, var_m1 = vcov), by = "grp") %>% 
    mutate(var_red = 1 - var_m1 / var_m0) 
}
#-------------------------- EXAMPLE OF USE:
cbind(M1 = R2_null(m0, m1.nc)[,4],
      M2 = R2_null(m0, m1.gmc)[,4],
      M3 = R2_null(m0, m1.cwc)[,4],
      M4 = R2_null(m0, m1.cmc)[,4]) %>%
  round(2) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd use lapply and a function on the list and then aggregate the results using cbind. The model "m1.cmc" didn't exist, so I used the fourth on you estimated from above.

```
#-------------------------- EXAMPLE OF USE:
cbind(M1 = R2_null(m0, m1.nc)[,4],
      M2 = R2_null(m0, m1.gmc)[,4],
      M3 = R2_null(m0, m1.cwc)[,4],
      M4 = R2_null(m0, m1.b_w)[,4]) %>%
  round(2) %>% as.data.frame()

l_models <- list(m1.nc, m1.gmc, m1.cwc, m1.b_w)
temp <- lapply(l_models, R2_null, m0 = m0)
temp2 <- cbind(lapply(temp, '[', 4))

result <- round(do.call(cbind, temp2), 2)
names(result) <- paste0('M', 1:4)
```